# MySQL order by position unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

`ORDER BY` column position does not appear to work in `MySQL`, though the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) states that it should.

Using the `employees' table` in the `Employees Sample Database` -

```
mysql> select first_name, last_name from employees order by 4;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '4' in 'order clause'
```

Here's the table -

```
mysql> describe employees;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Any idea what is happening?  The column name is in the select list so this should work.

Comment: Please use explicit column names (with aliases (if any)) only for ordering.

Comment: Use a proper `ORDER BY`.  What's wrong with using the actual column name?  Also you select 2 columns, but order by 4th column.  How do you expect it will work???

Answer (score 4):

The order by column position is based on the results of the query. In the case of your query you could select 1 (first_name) or 2 (last_name).

Order by column is not based on the position in the table.